# Independent and Identically distributed, conditional independent and Naive bayes

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, logistic-regression, naive-bayes

I'm reading about *Naive Bayes* classification concept, noting that we make the conditionally independence assumption. But isn't this the general assumption that is always made dealing with machine learning algorithms?

Suppose we have a supervised binary classification problem setup, with a dataset
$\mathcal{D} = \{(x_1,t_1), \dots, (x_n,t_n)\}$ where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^D$ and $t_i \in\{0,1\} \, \, \forall i=1, \dots n$.

I've read everywhere that we always make the assumption that data are iid (independent and with the same probability dstribution, this would mean that $p((x_i, t_i),(x_j,t_j)) = p((x_i,t_i))p((x_j,t_j))$..right?). At this point it is reasonable to think of a Bernoulli distribution to model the data. Let $p(\mathcal{D}|\theta)$ the likelihood function: then we want to find

$$\hat{\theta} = arg\max_{\theta}p(\mathcal{D}|\theta)$$

where $p(\mathcal{D}|\theta) = p((x_1,t_1), \dots ,(x_n,t_n)|\theta) = p((x_1,t_1)|\theta)\, , \dots , \, p((x_n,t_n)|\theta)$ Here we should use a *conditional* independence hypothesis in order to go on. So in every situation we use the naive bayes hypothesis? I'm having troubles trying to distinguish..

Answer (score 1):

In Naive Bayes, we assume that all features in
$x$ are mutually independent, conditional on the category
$C_k$.

The features can be height and weight and the category, $C$ can be whether your BMI is higher than certain quantity.

Here given $C$, we assume that height and weight are independent. The conditional independence is described for the features.